# Java, JDBC: Updating & displaying values in/from SQLite db

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

**Question:**

How do I update numberOfWins in the db as the program runs(rounds of poker are played), & at the end of program execution, display the data in/from my db?

**Background:**

This is a fairly standard console based poker game. Table is a dealer(creates hands) & executes rounds.  PokerGameMain, the main.  I also have classes for Card, Deck, Player, Wallet.  3 players are dealt cards, creating a hand, the hands are played, there is a winner & looser, this is a round.  I have included my current code on these classes for context.

My questions are about two database/JDBC/SQLite classes(SQLiteJDBC, Database) I am attempting to implement.  I've added these solely for learning purposes.  I'm attempting to gain knowledge of database/JDBC/SQLite & maven(which I have used to manage my SQLite dependency).

I've working pretty diligently at this program but I'm having a little trouble seeing how to pull it together.

**Question Again:**

*Primary)* How do I:

- Create a db(poker)...done I think.
- Create a table(players), with 2 columns(palyerName, numberOfWins)...done I think.
- Create 3 rows(player1-3)...done I think.
- Update numberOfWins in the db as the program runs(rounds of poker are played), & at the end of program execution, display the data in my db

*Secondary)* Suggestions regarding:

- My exception handling & design in SQLiteJDBC & Database

**SQLiteJDBC**

*Note:*

The only errors in the program that I know of are an *unchecked exception* & a can not resolve method.  Both in SQLiteJDBC, here & here:

```
 try {
        db.execute(dropTable);
        db.execute(createTable);
        db.execute(insertInto1);
        db.execute(insertInto2);
        db.execute(insertInto3);

        ResultSet resultSets = db.executeQuery(selectFrom);
        try {
            while (resultSets.next()) {
                // read the result set
                System.out.println("player = " + resultSets.getString("playerName"));
                System.out.println("number of wins = " + resultSets.getInt("numberOfWins"));
            }
        }
```

---

```
try {
            db.close();
        }



package com.craigreedwilliams.utilities;

import java.sql.*;

/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/10/2015.
 */
public class SQLiteJDBC {
    public static void passQuery() {
        String dropTable = "DROP TABLE if EXISTS players";
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE players(VARCHAR(25) playerName, INTEGER numberOfWins)";
        String insertInto1 = "INSERT INTO player1 VALUES ('player1', 0)";
        String insertInto2 = "INSERT INTO player2 VALUES ('player2', 0)";
        String insertInto3 = "INSERT INTO player3 VALUES ('player3', 0)";
        String selectFrom = "SELECT * FROM players";

        // Url for SqlLite
        String jdbcDbType = "jdbc:sqlite";
        String dbName = "poker.db";
        String dbUrl = jdbcDbType + ":" + dbName;

        Database db = new Database(dbUrl);
        try {
            db.execute(dropTable);
            db.execute(createTable);
            db.execute(insertInto1);
            db.execute(insertInto2);
            db.execute(insertInto3);

            ResultSet resultSets = db.executeQuery(selectFrom);
            try {
                while (resultSets.next()) {
                    // read the result set
                    System.out.println("player = " + resultSets.getString("playerName"));
                    System.out.println("number of wins = " + resultSets.getInt("numberOfWins"));
                }
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    resultSets.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            try {
                db.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Database**

```
package com.craigreedwilliams.utilities;

import java.sql.*;

/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/10/2015.
 */
public class Database {
    public String dbUrl;
    private String sqliteDriver = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
    private String driver;
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Statement statement = null;

    public Database() {

    }

    public Database(String dbUrl) {
        this.dbUrl = dbUrl;
      //  sqliteDriver = getDriverString(dbUrl);
        try {
            setConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setConnection() throws Exception {
        try {
            // registered DriverName using the current class loader
            Class.forName(sqliteDriver);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // connection failed
            System.out.println("DriverName: " + driver + " was not available");
            System.err.println(e);
            throw e;
        }
        // create a database connection
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
            connection = null;
        }
    }

    // this method should undoubtedly be public as we'll want to call this
    // to close connections externally to the class
    public void closeConnection() {
        if (statement!=null) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
        if (connection!=null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }

    // and we will definitely want to be able to call the following two
    // functions externally since they expose the database
    // behaviour which we are trying to access
    public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) throws SQLException {
        return statement.executeQuery(query);
    }

    public void execute(String query) throws SQLException {
        statement.executeUpdate(query);
    }

}
```

**PokerGameMain**

```
package com.craigreedwilliams.game;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class PokerGameMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Input Object of the scanner class
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice;

        System.out.println("Welcome to Poker Table! May the odds forever be in your favor :)");



        do {

            printMainGameWelcomeMenu();

            choice = input.nextInt();

            switch (choice){

                case 1:
                    //call start game method or class here
                    startGame();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //end game here
                    printMainGameGoodbyeMessage();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("The value you entered is outside of the range required for this application...");

            }

        } while (choice != 2);

    }


    public static void printMainGameWelcomeMenu(){

        System.out.println("This is the poker game's menu: \n"
                + "To start the game enter: 1\n"
                + "To end game enter: 2\n");
    }

    public static void printMainGameGoodbyeMessage(){

        System.out.println("Thank you for playing the poker game! Hope you enjoyed your experience. Have a great day! :D");
    }

    public static void startGame(){

        int count = 1;
        Table table = new Table();

        getUserInput(table);

        while (count < 4) {

            System.out.println("Round : " + count + "...\n");

            table.dealCards();
            table.showCards();

            count++;
        }


    }

    public static void getUserInput(Table table){

        Scanner usrInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean anteSet = false;

        System.out.println("Before the game starts, I will need some information...\n");

        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        String name = usrInput.nextLine();

        //set player name
        table.getPlayerAt(0).setPlayerName(name);


        // set ante
        do {
            System.out.println("How much are you willing to bet for every round? Keep in mind there will have to be at least three rounds...");
            Double ante = usrInput.nextDouble();

            if(checkAnte(ante, table.getPlayerAt(0).getWallet())) {
                table.getPlayerAt(0).setAnteValue(ante);
                anteSet = true;
            }
        }while (!(anteSet));

    }

    public static boolean checkAnte(double ante, Wallet wallet){

        if (ante * 3.0 > wallet.getBalance()) {
            System.out.println("Sorry your wallet balance is less than you think...Please reconsider the ante value");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            wallet.deductFromBalance(ante);
            System.out.println("Your ante for each round is set to be: " + ante + ". Good luck!");
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

**Table**

```
package com.craigreedwilliams.game;

/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/10/2015.
 */
public class Table {
    // two private attributes
    private Player[] players;
    private Deck deck;
    private double pot;
    private Player winner;


    /******************************************
     ** The array is set in the following way:
     ******************************************
     **  pairs are each given 1 point        **
     **  three of a kind are given 3 points  **
     **  straights are given 5 points        **
     **  flush are given 7 points            **
     **  four of a kind are given 8 points   **
     **  royal straights are given 10 points **
     **  royal flush are given 12 points     **
     ******************************************
     */
    private int[][] game = new int [7][2];

    // constructor initializes the deck and cards
    public Table() {
        deck = new Deck();
        players = new Player[3];
        players[0] = new Player();
        players[1] = new Player();
        players[2] = new Player();
        deck.shuffle();

    }

    // getter for player at the given index
    public Player getPlayerAt(int index){
        return players[index];
    }

    // deals the card to each player
    public void dealCards() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < players[0].getCards().length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < players.length; j++) {
                players[j].setCardAtIndex(deck.getCard(count++), i);
            }
        }
    }

    // simulates the game and shows the result
    public void showCards() {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Player " + (i + 1) + ": \n");
            for (int j = 0; j < players[0].getCards().length; j++) {
                System.out.println("{" + players[i].getCardAtIndex(j).toString() + "} ");
            }
            if(players[i].countPair() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Pair(S):" + players[i].countPair() + "! \n");
                game[0][i] += players[i].countPair();
            }
            if(players[i].isFlush()) {
                System.out.println("Flush! ");
            }
            if(players[i].isRoyalFlush())
                System.out.println("Royal Flush!!\n");
            if(players[i].isThreeOfAkind())
                System.out.println("Three of a kind! ");
            if(players[i].isFourOfAkind())
                System.out.println("Four of a kind!!\n");
            if(players[i].isStraight())
                System.out.println("Straight! \n");
            if(players[i].isRoyalStraight())
                System.out.println("Royal Straight!!\n");
            else
                System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Wallet**

```
package com.craigreedwilliams.game;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/11/2015.
 */
public class Wallet {
    private double balance;
    /**
     * default Wallet constructor
     */
    public Wallet() {
        setRandomStartingBalance(50.0, 500.0);
    }

    private void setRandomStartingBalance(double minimum, double maximum) {
        Random random = new Random();
        double randomStartingBalance = minimum + (maximum - minimum) * random.nextDouble();
        balance = randomStartingBalance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void deductFromBalance(double price) {
        this.balance = balance - price;
    }
}
```

**Player**

```js
package com.craigreedwilliams.game;

/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/10/2015.
 */
public class Player {
    private final static int MAX = 5;
    private Card cards[]; //hand
    private Deck tempDeck = new Deck();
    private Double anteValue = 0.0;


    private Wallet wallet;
    private String playerName = "";



    int gamesWon = 0;

    // private bools for checks
    private boolean pair = false;
    private boolean threeOfAkind = false;
    private boolean fourOfAkind = false;
    private boolean royalStraight = false;
    private boolean royalFlush = false;



    //constructor initializes 5 cards in each hand
    public Player() {
        cards = new Card[MAX];
        wallet = new Wallet();
    }

    // getters are setters for name and ante value
    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public Double getAnteValue() {
        return anteValue;
    }

    public void setAnteValue(Double anteValue) {
        this.anteValue = anteValue;
    }

    // getter for wallet for player object
    public Wallet getWallet() {
        return wallet;
    }

    // getter and setter for games won so far...
    public int getGamesWon() {
        return gamesWon;
    }

    public void setGamesWon(int gamesWon) {
        this.gamesWon = gamesWon;
    }

    //returns all the cards in hand
    public Card[] getCards() {
        return cards;
    }

    //get the cards at a particular position
    public Card getCardAtIndex(int index) {
        return (index >= 0 && index < MAX) ? cards[index] : null;
    }

    //sets the card at particular position
    public void setCardAtIndex(Card c, int index) {
        if(index >= 0 && index < MAX)
            cards[index] = c;
    }

    // basic bool return functions
    public boolean isRoyalStraight() {
        return royalStraight;
    }

    public boolean isThreeOfAkind() {
        return threeOfAkind;
    }

    public boolean isFourOfAkind() {
        return fourOfAkind;
    }

    public boolean isRoyalFlush() {
        return royalFlush;
    }

    //Main Logic here : public functions that check for all winning hands and change private boolean variables
    //                  appropriately

    //counts number of matched pair
    public int countPair() {

        int count = 0;
        //boolean pairCheck = ((!(threeOfAkind) && (!(fourOfAkind))));

        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < cards.length; j++)
            {
                if (cards[i].getRank().equals(cards[j].getRank())){
                    count++;
                    if (count == 1)
                        pair = true;
                    else if ((pair) && (count == 3)) {
                        threeOfAkind = true;
                        pair = false;
                    }
                    else if ((threeOfAkind) && (count == 4)) {
                        fourOfAkind = true;
                        threeOfAkind = false;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return (pair) ? count : 0;
    }

    //checks if it is a flush or not i.e all five cards of same suit also checks for royal flush
    public boolean isFlush()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < cards.length; j++) {
                if (cards[i].getSuit().equals(cards[j].getSuit())) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == 5){
                if (cards[i].getRankInt() == tempDeck.getRankInt(12))
                    royalFlush = true;
            }

        }
        return ((count == 5) && (!(royalFlush))) ? true : false;
    }

    //checks to see if it is a straight or royal straight or neither
    public boolean isStraight(){
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length - 1; i++){
            if ((cards[i].getRankInt() + 1 == cards[i + 1].getRankInt()) && (count < 4)){
                count++;
            }
            else if (count == 4){
                if (cards[i].getRankInt() == tempDeck.getRankInt(13)){
                    royalStraight = true;
                }
            }

        }

        return ((count == 4) && (!(royalStraight))) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

**Deck**

```
package com.craigreedwilliams.game;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/10/2015.
 */
public class Deck {
    private final String rank[] = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King", "Ace"};
    private final String suits[]={"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};

    private final int rankInt[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
    private final int suitsInt[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    private Card deck[];
    private final int MAX = 52;
    private Random randNum;

    //makes the deck, constructor - no arguments
    public Deck() {
        deck = new Card[MAX];

        //uses calendar object to get time stamp
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long seed = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        randNum = new Random(seed); // random generated using time seed

        // uses modulus operator
        for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++ ){
            deck[i] = new Card( rank[i % 13], suits[i / 13], rankInt[i % 13], suitsInt[i / 13]);
        }
    }

    //shuffles the deck
    public void shuffle(){

        for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++ ){
            int j = randNum.nextInt(MAX);
            Card c = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[j];
            deck[j] = c;
        }
    }

    //returns the individual card in the deck
    public Card getCard(int index){
        return deck[index];
    }

    //returns rankInt from the deck object at the given index value
    public int getRankInt(int index) {
        return rankInt[index];
    }

}
```

**Card**

```
package com.craigreedwilliams.game;

/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/10/2015.
 */
public class Card {
    private String rank;
    private String suit;
    private int rankInt;

    // TODO: remove this if actually never used
    private int suitInt;

    //four argument constructor initializes Cards rank and suit (stings and ints)
    public Card(String rank, String suit, int rankInt, int suitInt) {
        super();
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rankInt = rankInt;
        this.suitInt = suitInt;
    }

    //getter method to return the rank value
    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    //getter method to return the suit value
    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    //setter method to initialize the suit
    public int getRankInt() {
        return rankInt;
    }

    //return String representation of Card object
    public String toString() {
        return rank + " : " + suit;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you just want to update number of wins of each player?

Comment: you got it & then display my database values after all rounds(poker hands) have been played.

Comment: and each row is for each player?

Comment: That was my thought, but maybe you have a better idea?  This is new territory for me, I might not be seeing/thinking of this the right way.

Comment: "And at the end of each round you just need to query your SQL-Server." Do you also need an example for this? Then I´ll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query should look like this:

```
 Select Player,Wins From yourtable Set Wins=Wins + 1 Where Player=playerid
```

The columns are just examples because I don't know how you called them ;)

And at the end of each round you just need to query your SQL-Server.